# I get an error when I read a Github code in R

Tags: r

I Found this code on Github, but when I run it:

```
    Tracking <- ReadDLCDataFromCSV(file = "example/OFT/DLC_Data/OFT_3.csv", fps = 25)'
```

I get this error:

```
      Error in last(strsplit(file, split = "/")[[1]]) : 
      could not find function "last"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the source code of the function ReadDLCDataFromCSV(), from the GitHub link you linked, there is a function called `last` that is called. Line 34:

```
out$filename <- last(strsplit(file,split = "/")[[1]])
```

The error that you get is because the function last is not found. The function is probably from the `data.table` package. So install the data.table package with:

```
install.packages("data.table")
```

and then load the package with:

```
library("data.table")
```

The ReadDLCDataFromCSV() function should then work. The package data.table is noted as a dependency to the DLCAnalyzer collection as noted in the README.md.

Comment: @SkylerNight Please select the answer as accepted, if it works. So if anyone else with a similar question will know that the solution worked.